# How to have two leading blanks using savetxt in Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, fortran

I am preparing a file in Python to be read in Fortran. The file looks like this:

```
 0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  1.5000000E-01
 1.0193980E-02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  1.5000000E-01
 2.0387960E-02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  1.5000000E-01
 3.0581940E-02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  1.5000000E-01
 4.0775920E-02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  1.5000000E-01
 5.0969900E-02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  1.5000000E-01
 6.1163880E-02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  1.5000000E-01
 7.1357860E-02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  1.5000000E-01
 8.1551840E-02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  1.5000000E-01
```

it starts with one leading blank space and then the spacing between columns becomes 2 blanks. The Fortran executable that I have (no access to the source code), reads and writes `E15.7` format which means I need two leading blanks like the following:

```
  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  1.5000000E-01
  1.0193980E-02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  1.5000000E-01
  2.0387960E-02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  1.5000000E-01
  3.0581940E-02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  1.5000000E-01
  4.0775920E-02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  1.5000000E-01
  5.0969900E-02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  1.5000000E-01
  6.1163880E-02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  1.5000000E-01
  7.1357860E-02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  1.5000000E-01
  8.1551840E-02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  1.5000000E-01
```

My python script that produce the file is like this:

```
np.savetxt(fpath, data, fmt='%14.7E')
```

If I use `fmt='%15.7E'` the leading blanks becomes two but the rest of the spaces will be 3.

Comment: If `fmt` describes one column it is replicated and joined with the `delimiter`.  Alternatively it can describe the whole line as @Stephen shows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a bit more involved format string you can do that like:

#### Code:

```
np.savetxt(fpath, data, fmt=' %14.7E' * data.shape[1])
```

#### Test Code:

```
import numpy as np
fpath = 'test_data'
data = np.array([[1.0, 1.1, 12.0]])
np.savetxt(fpath, data, fmt=' %14.7E' * data.shape[1])
```

#### Results:

```
  1.0000000E+00  1.1000000E+00  1.2000000E+01
```